# Is it enough to show the parity of numerical function from only the table of it variation?

Tags: real-analysis, education, calculus-of-variations, parity

Really i want to know if i can show the parity of any numerical function if i have only the table of it variation , for example if i take the below table of variation of the function $f$ defined over $[-2,2] $

> >
>   \begin{array}{c|cc|} 
>  x &      -2 & 0 &  2\\ \hline
> f(x) &   4 \searrow & 0 & \nearrow 4
>  \end{array}
>   Then is it possible to say the function $f$ is even since satisfy the symetric domain ?

Answer (score 1):

**No** The table of variations contains only the intervals where the function is monotonic and the amplitude of the variations on these intervals. These details don't suffice to say if a function is even.